# Custom event parameter showing as "(not set)" in reports (but shows in realtime)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We are sending an event (e.g. `example_event`) via gtag from our website to track an interaction with the page. Along with this event, we send a custom parameter (e.g. `example_param`).

The **event** is tracked correctly and we can report on the event count via Explorations and Reports. **The custom parameter is not**.

The custom parameter is defined as a "Custom dimension" like so:
[image: Custom dimension]

The custom parameter shows up in the realtime report just fine:

[image: Realtime report custom parameter]

But in Explorations and Reports, the custom parameter is returned as "(not set)".

Why is this happening? We have been troubleshooting for a few hours and are unable to find any issue with the setup. Note that we not using GTM.

We have:

- Verified that the custom parameter shows in DebugView
- Waited at least one week after defining the custom dimension before re-running the reports

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: how are you setting the data to the custom-dimension? is it a dataLayer variable? are you using google tag manager?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami no GTM (due to technical requirements). It is not a dataLayer variable. It is: `gtag('event', 'example_event', { example_param: 'example' });`

Comment: 1- have you checked the exact spelling you used  while creating custom dimension and the the one which is used by front-end developers?
2- have you checked on inspect window the value you are actually sending to GA4? there are tools and extensions that you can check. since I use GTM and dataLayer, mine is called exactly datalayer. you can serach for other suitable tools

Comment: @ShilaMosammami 1 - spelling (case, underscores, etc) is the exact same, 2 - the value is being sent (we can see it in the request payload) and it's coming up in the realtime report. Just not explore reports.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the comment, you have not used `'` around the custom dimension.  you should use single quotes around the parameter name, like this: ‘example_param’. This is because gtag.js expects the parameter name to be a string, and strings in JavaScript are enclosed by either single or double quotes. If you omit the quotes, gtag.js will treat the parameter name as a variable, which may cause errors or unexpected results. For example, if you write

```
 gtag(‘event’, ‘example_event’, { example_param: ‘example’ });
```

**without quotes**, gtag.js will look for a **variable named** **example_param** in the **global scope**, and if it does not find it, it will send **undefined** as the parameter name to GA4. This will make it difficult to identify and analyze the custom event and parameter in `GA4` reports. Therefore, it is recommended to always use quotes around the parameter name when using gtag.js.

So try:

gtag(‘event’, ‘example_event’, { 'example_param': ‘example’ });

please have a look at this link:
[Set up event parameters Example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/event-parameters?client_type=gtag)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The param is being sent fine -- it's coming up in realtime reports and it's in the request payload. It's just exploration reports that aren't working

Comment: @DanielHunt, Are you dealing with a large number of Data? Google Analytics sometimes uses sampling in its reports, especially if you're dealing with large datasets. This can lead to some data not being shown. However, this typically wouldn't result in a "(not set)" value for a parameter that's consistently passed.

Comment: Have you checked Dimension-Metric Compatibility, Not all dimensions and metrics can be paired together in reports due to the way they're processed by Google Analytics. Ensure that your custom dimension and any associated metrics you're using in the Exploration report are compatible. the second issue to control is If you're using secondary dimensions in your report or not, ensure they are compatible with your custom dimension. Sometimes, adding a secondary dimension can cause specific primary dimension values to appear as "(not set)".

Comment: It's working now.... it's due to a silly fault on my part. Looking at change history, the custom dimension was created on October 3rd -- I was under the assumption it was created when we migrated to GA4. It's started showing in reports from the last few days (date range on test explorations was September, so running a report for yesterday now pulls the custom dimension). Thank you for your help.